# Setting OnClickListener for array of checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have an array of checkboxes that all need an OnClickListener to see when they're checked/unchecked. Here's what I have:

```
CheckBox[] sens = new CheckBox[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cb = new CheckBox(this);
    cb.setText(strings[i]);
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View v) {
                                  if (cb.isChecked()) {
                                      System.out.println("Checked");
                                  } else {
                                      System.out.println("Unchecked");
                                  }
                              }
                          });
    sens[i] = cb;
    mainlayout.addView(sens[i]);
}
```

But the monitor/console only prints "Unchecked", no matter if it's checked or not. Is there a better method to do this? The checkboxes need to be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` method instead of `setOnClickListener`, and you can use the `setTag` method to set a position/id to handle the checkboxes.

**Documentation**: Register a callback to be invoked when the checked state of this button changes.

```
private void createCheckBoxes(final int count) {
    for (int i = 0;i < count; i++) {
        final CheckBox checkBox = createCheckBox(this, strings[i], i);
        mainlayout.addView(checkBox);
    }
}

private CheckBox createCheckBox(final Context context, final String text, final int id) {
    final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);

    checkBox.setTag(id);
    checkBox.setText(text);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                System.out.println("Checked");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unchecked");
            }
        }
    });

    return checkBox;
}
```